# Finding roots at right half-plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $P(z)\in\mathbb{C}[z]$ be a polynomial with complex coefficients.

(1) Prove that if all zeroes of $P$ are in the right plane $Re z\geq 0$, then the same is true for $P'(z)$.

(2) Deduce that $x^5+2x^4-3x^3-4x^2-5x-6$ has at least one root in the left half-plane $Rez\leq 0$.

Is there any hint on how to approach this question? I was thinking to use the Mobius transformation to convert right half plane to unit circle and apply the $\int_C\frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}dw$ but I do not know how to proceed afterwards.

Comment: See [Gauss-Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem).

Comment: @Calvin Lin Could you elaborate a bit...I couldnot get you...sorry

Comment: Read the statement of the theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$\Re(\sum_j \frac1{z-a_j})<0$ for $\Re(z)< 0$